# truncate to datagridview cells to significant digits while keeping datatable values the same

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

So I'm not sure if this is possible to solve, but essentially I have a data table with cells that are doubles, many of which extend out to a lot of precision. My dilemma is that this data table is bound to a data grid view control, and this high precision is not useful for the user to see on the data grid view. Is there any way to truncate the values displayed on the data grid view, without losing the precision in the Data Table it is bound to? Essentially I would like the user to see a double like 4.477976... as 4.48 in the data grid view, but to retain its original value for manipulation within the data table class. Thanks for any help you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the CellStyle Format for that column.  For example:

```
    // doubleValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn with precision = 2
    // 
    this.doubleValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Double_Value_Data";
    dataGridViewCellStyle2.Format = "N2";
    dataGridViewCellStyle2.NullValue = null;
    this.doubleValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
    this.doubleValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Double_Value_Data";
    this.doubleValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "doubleValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
```

You can also do this in the designer if using Visual Studio and you have a static bound control.